# Java GUI Creation Using 2dGraphics

Tags: user-interface, graphics, 2d

I noticed swing is really hard to make a GUI look good. Instead of using JComponents, can you bind somehow text, images, buttons, etc. to 2dgraphic instead of using swing. In other words I would like to give it my own look and feel. If you have any examples of a program that does this feel free to let me know. If 2dgraphics used in a GUI is not the conventional way to customize GUI's. Educate me on the alternatives. My mind is wide open.

Thanks,

StoneAgeProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom look and feel but it's a fair bit of work: 
https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html

A simpler solution might be to customize swing components as best you can. Maybe using your own images as backgrounds for buttons for eg:

```
JButton button=new JButton(new ImageIcon("urltoimage.###"));
```

and then modify the attributes until to get the effect you want:

```
button.setOpaque(false);button.setContentAreaFilled(false);button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

There's a million things you could try.